# Two RewriteCond and RewriteRule working independently

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have two rules. Each rule does exactly what it should when its in the `.htaccess` by itself, but when both rules are there they start to conflict with each other.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above rule works fine for getting say `http://domain.com/12.html` and passing the number `12` into `index.php` **only** if the number finishes with `.html` (note `12.html` file does not exist!)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\.html [L,R=301]
```

This works fine for checking if the URL ends with `.html`. And if it DOES NOT finish with `.html`, it will redirect it to the URI + `.html` (this also works fine by itself).

When I have both rules in the one `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\.html [L,R=301]
```

then there is a loop resulting in a redirect loop.

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you just use the second rewrite rule, what does it do with `http://domain.com/index.php?id=12`?

Comment: it returnn: http://domain.com/index.php.html?id=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first rule rewrites `http://domain.com/12.html` into `http://domain.com/index.php?id=12`. Then things start going awry; the second rule rewrites that into `http://domain.com/index.php.html?id=12`, but at that point I think you'll find that the first rule kicks in again, rewriting that into something like `http://domain.com/index.php?id=index.php`, which the second rule rewrites into `http://domain.com/index.php.html?id=index.php`. At this point I think the rules end up fighting over the URL.

The easiest solution is probably to tweak the second rewrite rule not to rewrite pages that already contain an extension, i.e. use `[^.]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: your solution did in fact work for any id thats an int, but sadly it doesnt work whent he ID is say a decimal like 123.23 I continue to experiment and came up with this that so far seems to work:

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.html$`
- `RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0\.html [L,R=301]`

- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$`
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?ip=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention that you wanted to support decimal numbers. In that case, perhaps you could have used `[.0-9]*` instead?